# Designing a unipolar stepper driver using STM32 MCU, lack of torque

Tags: stm32, pwm, stepper-motor, torque, stepper-driver

I am working on my first robotics project which will hopefully become a desktop sized [KUKA iiwa](https://www.kuka.com/en-us/products/robotics-systems/industrial-robots/lbr-iiwa). Unfortunately, I have only just completed the first year of my electrical engineering degree so have been struggling with this problem for a few months.

The plan is to use the STM32 board to control 4 or 5 stepper motors simultaneously. To make this more challenging (possibly too challenging) and to reduce cost I am attempting to drive unipolar motors with MOSFETs switched by signals from the MCU via a gate driver. The image below shows the signal generated by the MCU, please ignore the time base, this picture was taken during initial testing.

[image: Signal generated by MCU, ignore time base, this picture was taken during initial testing]

After playing around with this for months it has proven impossible to achieve the rated torque at any frequency and I am now desperate for ideas. Recent developments have been adding a gate driver to increase the maximum current through the MOSFETs and adding freewheel diodes across each coil. The circuit diagram below does not show the gate driver but does show how the circuit lacks complexity. Here I have used a resistor and inductor to model each coil.

[image: Circuit diagram]

I have managed to get the motor to spin relatively quickly, using pulse width modulation to give a burst of max voltage at the beginning of the step then a lower pulse width for the rest of the step. I believe this is how a chopper driver limits current. The reason for the 100% duty cycle at the beginning of the step is to allow the current to rise. I can adjust the duration of this pulse, but have calculated that at 20 V it needs 120 microseconds to reach the 1.2 A current rating. In my most recent testing, measuring current in one coil using an inline resistor and oscilloscope. I have found that the current rises much quicker than this. I think this could be the cause of the problem as the current must continue to flow when the mosfet is off, creating a magnetic field that weakens the effect of the next step? The following picture shows the current rising rapidly(blue) to 2A though it shouldn't have the time to reach this current.

[image: Picture showing current rising instantly]

I have tested a single coil with a pulse of 12 V to confirm my calculations for rise time in the inductor are correct. I am now using 20 V so the current can rush in faster. This must mean that in the high frequency application, the current is continuing to flow in the coil via the diode when the mosfet is in its closed state, matching my previous theory. Is there any way to stop this current flowing for so long?

[image: 12V current ramp]

Increasing the duty cycle of the second stage of each pulse seems to be the best way of improving torque, however this causes the motor to get exceptionally hot.

Comment: Put a resistor in series with the back emf diode to burn the energy faster but, make sure your MOSFET can handle the increased drain voltage.

Comment: Thank you, @Andyaka. I had a similar theory, but was unsure how to determine the resistance required, power rating and which side of the diode it should go (Anode or Cathode)?